# xslt select tablerow by multiple colmn values

Tags: xslt, search, multiple-columns, xmltable

I got following XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
        <row>
          <column>
            <name>COL_A</name>
            <string>xxx</string>
          </column>
          <column>
            <name>COL_B</name>
            <currency>yyy</currency>
          </column>
          <column>
            <name>COL_C</name>
            <number>zzz</number>
          </column>
        </row>
        <row>
          <column>
            <name>COL_A</name>
            <string>aaa</string>
          </column>
          <column>
            <name>COL_B</name>
            <currency>bbb</currency>
          </column>
          <column>
            <name>COL_C</name>
            <number>ccc</number>
          </column>
          </row>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to dectect wether a row with the triple of columns/values exist 
(COL_A = aaa and COL_B = bbb and COL_C = ccc)

I wrote this xslt, but I only could match the first pair and dont know, how to go ahead...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:template match="Envelope">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Body/row"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(column/name = 'COL_A') and (column/string = 'xxx' )">
                <xsl:text> Found </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I wrote that script to understand how to find the row with these values (aaa,bbb,ccc).
Afterwards I need, if possible, a xpath-statement just to check, wether a row with these values exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `and`-combine three node-existence-tests in the `xsl:when`. So to match the second `row` do

```
column[name = 'COL_A' and string = 'aaa'] and column[name = 'COL_B' and currency = 'bbb'] and column[name = 'COL_C' and number = 'ccc']
```

This XPath-1.0 expression fulfills your requirement.

---

Here is the whole test stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

    <xsl:template match="/soap:Envelope">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="soap:Body/row"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="column[name = 'COL_A' and string = 'aaa'] and column[name = 'COL_B' and currency = 'bbb'] and column[name = 'COL_C' and number = 'ccc']">
                <xsl:text> Found </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```